# Poor performance with QSyntaxHighlighter of QTextEdit

Tags: c++, xml, qt, syntax-highlighting, highlight

In  [Syntax Highlighting in QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq21-syntaxhighlighter.html) example, I want highlight xml text in a QTextEdit, so change only some part of text, like the one in the angle brackets, and not all text.

All work properly, but with big file, the software not responding.

is there any way to slow down the refresh Or as an alternative refresh only the visible part of the QTextEdit?

Thank you

Comment: Are you testing a release / optimized build?

Comment: The document that you attach was for `Qt 4` as I see `Porting to Qt 4.2's Graphics View`. Are you using `Qt 4` ???

Comment: "Are you testing a release / optimized build? " No, I tested only in debugging, but I want that working properly also in debug.

Currently I use Qt5.

Comment: I think you should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. In that way, I can fix your program. and don't read `Qt 4` docs because they are old and now qt provide lots of function and classes.

Comment: I use exactly the code of the example, with Qt5 and working properly, except for big file.
In other words, my problem is eactly this one:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/104688/is-there-a-way-to-optimise-qsyntaxhighlighter-for-really-big-files/3

Comment: On msvc debug mode can be 100 times slower than release in some cases that is why I asked. I have experienced that with testing lung segmentation code in my research at work where the release mode took several  seconds  and debug took over a day. Thankfully I did not have to use the debug mode often with the full resolution cases.

Comment: @valeriot90 -- A debug build is meant for debugging, not for speed.  You should use a reduced size file for debugging purposes.

Comment: I confirm that even in release the performance are poor

Comment: `QTextEdit`'s performance is notoriously bad with very large files because they always load the whole file and make layout for it. `QPlainTextEdit` could be a bit faster. Syntax highlighter will make it even slower. When used for example of XML files of 10 MB of size, it is mission impossible. If you learn about a text edit which loads only the visible portions of file, let me know.

Comment: @valeriot90 -- Don't expect a class like `QTextEdit` to outperform fine-tuned, commercial (and some non-commercial) text editors.  If you look at a commercial text editor that can load large files, I can bet they are not simply using `QTextEdit` or similar type to perform the way they do.  Developing "fast" text-editing features is not trivial.  Might as well find a true text-editing widget, component, source, etc. instead of something "generic" and is not meant for speed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way For `Highlighting in QTextEdit`:

I add one `QTextEdit` in my UI file :

[image]

and In `mainwindow.cpp` **Just add this:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->textEdit->setTextBackgroundColor(Qt::yellow);
}
```

means `setTextBackgroundColor(Qt::yellow);`

**This is its result:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I had to add details. With highlights xml text, I mean change only some part of text, like the one in the angle brackets, and not all text

Comment: @valeriot90 It doesn't matter you can use this way when you want to change only some part of the text. you can create one button and when you select some text then only the selected text be Highlighted.